# Which part should I lock when dealing with both read and write?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, mutex

I'm playing with C++(11) STL and got the following problem.
The basic idea for this code is:
I have a "trigger" function, an "add" function and a flag(false by default). If the flag is false the "add" function's going to push the threadID to a queue, otherwise it's going to insert the threadID to the set. When the trigger function is called, it set the flag to "true" and move threadIDs from the queue to the set.
I initialized 100 threads and use one of the thread to run the trigger function(in the code it's thread NO.30). Ideally the result should have 0 elements in the queue and 99 elements in the set.
However, sometimes the result is correct, sometimes I missed some numbers in the set, and sometimes I got the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.
Could anyone help? Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
using namespace std;


bool flag = false;
queue<int> q;
unordered_set<int> s;
mutex mu;

void trigger()
{
    mu.lock();
    flag = true;
    mu.unlock();
    while( !q.empty() ){
        s.insert(q.front());
        q.pop();
    }
}

void add(int id)
{
    mu.lock();
    if( !flag ) 
        q.push(id);
    else {
        if ( s.find(id) == s.end() ){
            s.insert(id);
        }
    }
    mu.unlock();
}

void missing()
{
    cout << "Missing Numbers: ";
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        if( s.find(i) == s.end() ) 
            cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    vector<thread> threads;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        if ( i == 29 ) threads.push_back(thread(trigger));
        else threads.push_back(thread(add, i+1));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        threads[i].join();
    }
    cout << "Q size: " << q.size() << endl;
    cout << "S size: " << s.size() << endl;
    missing();
}
```

Comment: "Ideally the result should have 9 elements in the queue and 99 elements in the set." Why? The `trigger` function _pops_ anything in the queue out.

Comment: sorry for the wrong statement. Should be 0 elements in the queue and 99 elements in the set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 1 thread executing the `trigger` function and many threads executing the `add` function. Furthermore, you take care to guard some of the shared state but not all of it. See my comments/questions in the below code snippets.

```
void trigger()
{
    // Only the 'flag' is protected from concurrent acceess
    mu.lock();
    flag = true;
    mu.unlock();

    // Why isn't 'q' or 's' protected by a lock?
    while( !q.empty() ){
        s.insert(q.front());
        q.pop();
    }
}

void add(int id)
{
    // In this function both 'q' and 's' are protected from concurrent access
    mu.lock();
    if( !flag ) 
        q.push(id);
    else {
        if ( s.find(id) == s.end() ){
            s.insert(id);
        }
    }
    mu.unlock();
}
```

### Possible Solution

In general, you should protect any state being accessed concurrently. I'd also recommend using a *lock* type (e.g., [lock_guard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard)) instead of locking and unlocking the mutex directly (research RAII for why this is encouraged).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool flag = false;
queue<int> q;
unordered_set<int> s;
mutex mu;

void trigger()
{
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(mu);
    flag = true;

    while (!q.empty())
    {
        s.insert(q.front());
        q.pop();
    }
}

void add(int id)
{
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(mu);

    if (!flag)
    {
        q.push(id);
    }
    else
    {
        if (s.find(id) == s.end())
        {
            s.insert(id);
        }
    }
}

void missing()
{
    cout << "Missing Numbers: ";
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)
    {
        if (s.find(i) == s.end())
        {
            cout << i << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    vector<thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        if (i == 29)
        {
            threads.push_back(thread(trigger));
        }
        else
        {
            threads.push_back(thread(add, i + 1));
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        threads[i].join();
    }

    cout << "Q size: " << q.size() << endl;
    cout << "S size: " << s.size() << endl;
    missing();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That works! Thank you James. Just wondering in your solution, you used two lock_guards in the trigger function, why don't you use just one lock_guard at the beginning and then it will automatically release at the end of the function? In addition, if I change the "flag" type to "atomic_bool" or "atomic_flag", will there be any improvements?

Comment: @user110921 I wasn't sure what the behavior of the `trigger` function should be but there isn't any reason it can't use a single lock around the whole function. I don't see why an atomic would help in this case since you already need a lock to protect the `queue` and `set`.

Comment: @user110921 I updated the `trigger` function to use a single lock since that implementation is more straight forward.

Comment: what if I'm going to have multiple threads running the "trigger" function, but the "flag" should be set only once, this case, should I change the type of "flag"? Should I use the so called "lazy initialization"?

Comment: @user110921 Even if you allowed multiple threads to execute the `trigger` function I don't see why you should change the `flag` type. Perhaps I'm missing the point you're making. You may want to consider asking 1 or more new questions so that other experts may assist in answering. I have some experience with multithreading but I'm sure there are others that are much more knowledgeable than myself on this topic.